# Pandas read_csv (quickly!) with non-regex, multi-char sep

Tags: python, pandas, file-io

I am often given a file with `,`  (comma-space) separators that I would like to read into a pandas dataframe. The straightforward `pd.read_csv(fname, header=0, sep=', ')` reads just fine, but is ~8x slower (than an equivalent `sep=','`) on my files, because the multi-char sep appears like a regex and forces the python engine.

What is good way (main metric: fast) to read files with non-regex, multi-char delimiters without needing to fallback onto the python engine? My current solution (posted below) essentially runs `s/, /,/g` on the file first, but this requires passing over the file twice. Is there a preferred solution without this drawback?

Answer (score 1):

use `df = pd.read_csv(fname, skipinitialspace=True)` as :

```
skipinitialspacebool, default False
Skip spaces after delimiter.
```

a refer: [Dealing with extra white spaces while reading CSV in Pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-extra-white-spaces-while-reading-csv-in-pandas-67b0c2b71e6a)

Comment: Fantastic, bit of an RTFM on my part, much appreciated! Works perfectly for my use case, but I'll leave my answer in case someone else has a non-whitespace mutli-char sep.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to simply replace the delimiter with a single-char before calling `read_csv`.

```
from io import StringIO
def read_comma_space(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().replace(', ', ',')
    s = StringIO(text)
    return pd.read_csv(s, header=0, sep=',')
```

This enables use of the C engine, but must make multiple passes over the file. Compared to a baseline read of the file (`read_csv(fname, header=0, sep=',')`), this solution adds about 50% to total execution time in my tests. This is much better than the ~8x execution time over the baseline of the python engine.